Azure Data Factory Zip Archive Support
Using Azure Data Factory I have been trying to do the following for to create a D365 Finance and Operations DMF Package API zip file using the native operators in ADF:

Create a new Excel or CSV file in Blob Storage via a Data Flow
Copy XML Package Header and Manifest XML files into the same directory in Blob Storage
Create a zip archive of these files in the same directory

This is a relatively trivial task, but it seems the operators within ADF are fairly limited. From what I can see in the documentation:

Deflate compression is available where writing to a Delimited Text Sink

But it is not available in general for a group of files (for example, using a Binary Sink to make it general purpose).
I know this is achievable this using some code via an Azure Function call for example. However, there is a reluctance to adopt other technologies outside of the core ADF features.
Is there anything I am missing with ADF, or is this just not possible without getting another service to do it?

You can achieve your requirement using Binary datasets in the ADF copy activity.
After generating the required files in the directory, create Binary datasets for source and target.
In the source Binary dataset, give your folder location and don't give any file names.

These are the starting files that I have in the zipinput folder.
billing.xml
first.xml
sample1.csv
Second.xml

In the target dataset, give your folder location and give a name for the zip file <filename>.zip. You can give the Deflate(.zip) compression here.

Give these two datasets as the copy activity source and sink and debug the copy activity. Now, it will create required .zip file in the given location.

Inside .zip file:

You can copy this .zip file to your required location using copy activity with Binary datasets.

Thanks for the demonstration @rakesh-govindula - this looks perfect. However, when I try to run this, I receive the error ErrorCode=UserErrorZipCopyBehaviorNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=CopyBehavior property is not supported if the compression type of sink is Zip.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'. Cannot find any details anywhere on it.

The copy behavior should be set to None.

If you want to use, copy behavior, first you need to copy the required files to temp location (use binary source and sink without any compression) with required copy behavior in a copy activity. Then, follow the above approach from temp location to required location with another copy activity.

Wow that works perfectly, amazing!
